# Write a query that gets Poorly Mastered records and correctly Mastered Records?

Tags: sql, sql-server, oracle

1. I have to write a query to that has all correctly mastered recipients ( group by first_name and last_name)
2. I have to write another query that have all poorly mastered recipients ( group by first_name , last_name)
3. Please see the images below if there are multiple Master Id's against First Name and Last Name then its poorly Mastered.. if it have same Master ID then its correctly Mastered.
4. Sample data for the query is provided below

[image]
[image]

```
WITH DATA1 AS
(
  SELECT 5175133 ID,'Yun'  FIRST_NAME,'Yue' LAST_NAME,NULL MASTER_ID FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5157093,'Yun','Yue',5157093 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5226656,'Yun','Yue',NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  6345852,'Yun','Yue',5157093 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5882603,'Ye','Han',5157093 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5902219,'Ye','Han',5157093 FROM dual UNION ALL

  SELECT  6362890,'Rick','Kaylor',NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  6362940,'Rick','Kaylor',NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5215659,'Rick','Kaylor',NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5962837,'Rick','Kaylor',5962837 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5841556,'Rick','Kaylor',5841556 FROM dual UNION ALL

  SELECT  5916218,'Sherlene','Heard',5916218 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  6356086,'Sherlene','Heard',5916218 FROM dual UNION ALL

  SELECT  5885157,'Ye','Kong',5884937 FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5884937,'Ye','Kong',NULL FROM dual UNION ALL
  SELECT  5898890,'Ye','Kong',5884937 FROM dual 
 )

 SELECT * FROM DATA1
```

I think its  a simple query please provide help?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

As this is very probably some kind of homework or assignment, just a clue:

Have you think about using `COUNT(*)` in a sub-query ? As far as I can tell, "correctly mastered recipients" will all have one and only one `master_id`...

Comment: Thanks for your reply but the image which is displaying correctly mastered records is right .... it can have multiple Master_ID's appearances but Master_ID should be same

Comment: @Ali Yes you can. But with a proper `GROUP BY` clause this shouldn't be an issue. As I said, _"just a clue"_ -- but by thinking a little bit more about that you can probably solve your issue yourself now. Good luck!